# WPF printing in Landscape

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a `DocumentPaginator` that needs to be printed landscape.

My first thought was to this:

```
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;
```

Problem is that this returns an **error** of

> The type or namespace name 'PageOrientation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Printing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Before you say it yes I have `using System.Printing;` and System.Printing is a references.

Why is this error occurring?

edit:  Solution;

Turns out after doing a clean solution and then doing build the actually error was given.  Turns out **ReachFramework.dll** was required as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Visual Studio is not able to resolve names in XAML in the project or solution.may be after rebuilding your solution everything  will works fine.

Then do a rebuild.

Comment: That seemed to help.  the problem actually was that it also needed ReachFramework.dll